# ExtJs version upgrade

Tags: extjs, extjs4

What are the things to be done for upgrading ExtJs version 4.0.7 to 4.2.1?
I am getting many errors. But the error is in ext-all.js
So I cant detect the error. Also the eclipse is stuck after some time if I downloaded and copy the ExtJs folder into the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

When you're debugging, you should include `ext-all-debug.js` or `ext-debug-w-comments.js`, or `ext-all-dev.js` instead of `ext-all.js`. All three versions will give you a readable version of the code (i.e. not minified), and the `-dev` one will also output useful warnings, etc.

Concerning Eclipse, that's just a guess but it seems that it get stuck trying to parsing and understanding the huge `ext-all.js` file. I know that Netbeans can't open it, but it won't try to parse it before one try to open the file. PHPStorm (WebSphere) can open it, but it is not free.

So, try to exclude the Ext source directory from the source Eclipse is parsing. In order to see Ext's code, try to open individual class files instead, any IDE should be able to handle these.

Anyway in your situation, the tool that will be the most useful to track down all you errors will be the browser debugger. In my experience, Chrome will be a lot faster than Firefox to debug huge JS files.

Comment: I use ext-all-dev.js (it gives you even more, useful warnings/logging) + intelliJ (also not free :( ) It can handle the ext lib very good! I too use Chrome for debugging. Still the large ExtJS libs requires a little memory and cpu power but it's certainly doable

Comment: You're right for `ext-all-dev.js`, even better. PhpStorm is a version of IntelliJ nerfed down to PHP + web. I switched to it because of its Ext support, so I couldn't agree more.